# Can I call Monitor.Pulse from a different class in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-synchronization

In an application that I am developing I will be using 2 threads to do various operations. (I will not go into detail here.) These threads work in loops, checking if there is work to be done, doing work, calculating the time they need to wait and waiting. (See below)

```
public Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  private static Thread StartingDateThread;
  private static Thread DeadlineDateThread;
  private static object o1;
  private static object o2;

  public static Thread GetStartingDateThreadInstance
  {
     get
       {
         if(StartingDateThread==null)
          {
             StartingDateThread=new Thread(new ThreadStart(MonitorStartingDates));
          }
          return StartingDateThread;
       }
  }

public static Thread GetDeadlineThreadInstance
  {
     get
       {
         if(DeadlineDateThread==null)
          {
             DeadlineDateThread=new Thread(new ThreadStart(MonitorDeadlines));
          }
          return DeadlineDateThread;
       }
  }

 public static object GetFirstObjectInstance
  {
     get
       {
         if(o1==null)
          {
             o1=new object();
          }
          return o1;
       }
  }

 public static object GetSecondObjectInstance
   {
     get
      {
        if(o2==null)
         {
          o2=new object();
         }
         return o2;
      }
  }

  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      GetStartingDateThreadInstance.Start();
      GetDeadlineThreadInstance.Start();
      //////////////////////
      ////Do other stuff.
  }


   public void MonitorStartingDates()
   {
      while(true)
      {
           //Check if there is stuff to do.
           //Do stuff if available.
           //Check if there will be stuff to do in the future and if there is, check
           //the time to wake up.
           //If there is nothing to do, sleep for a pre-determined 12 hours.

         if(StuffToDoInFuture)
         {
          Monitor.Enter(GetFirstObjectInstance);
          Monitor.Wait(WaitingTime);
          Monitor.Exit(GetFirstObjectInstance);
         }
         else
         {
          Monitor.Enter(GetFirstObjectInstance);
          Monitor.Wait(new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0));
           Monitor.Exit(GetFirstObjectInstance);
         }
      }
   }

  public void MonitorDeadlines()
  {
      while(true)
      {
           //Check if there is stuff to do.
           //Do stuff if available.
           //Check if there will be stuff to do in the future and if there is, check
           //the time to wake up.
           //If there is nothing to do, sleep for a pre-determined 3 days and 12 hours.

         if(StuffToDoInFuture)
         {
          Monitor.Enter(GetSecondObjectInstance);
          Monitor.Wait(WaitingTime);
          Monitor.Exit(GetSecondObjectInstance);
         }
         else
         {

             Monitor.Enter(GetSecondObjectInstance);
             Monitor.Wait(new TimeSpan(3, 12, 0, 0));
             Monitor.Exit(GetSecondObjectInstance);
         }

      }
  }
```

As you can see these two threads are started in the Application_Start method in the asax file. They operate if there is stuff available to do and then they calculate the time period they need to wait and then they wait. However, as users of the web application do operations new records will be inserted into the database and there will be circumstances where any of the two threads will have to resume operation sooner than planned. So, say I have a method in my DataAccess class which inserts into the database new data. (See below)

```
  public class DataAccess
  {
      ///////////////
      //
      public void InsertNewAuction()
      {
        ///Insert new row calculate the time
          Monitor.Pulse(Global.GetFirstObjectInstance);
          Monitor.Pulse(Global.GetSecondObjectInstance);
       ///
      }
   }
```

It seems like this is an invalid operation, because at the stage where the Monitor.Pulse is called from the InsertNewAuction method I get an exception. Something like "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." Is there any way of doing this? Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not use a publish/subscribe model? ala ServiceBus

Answer (score 2):

As to the specific error you're seeing, this is because [Monitor.Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) must be called inside the Monitor lock, like this (I've used lock rather than Enter/Exit, as it's safer for making sure the lock is always released, since it uses a proper try/finally block):

```
lock (Global.GetFirstObjectInstance)
{
   Monitor.Pulse(Global.GetFirstObjectInstance);
}
```

In regard to the more general design question here, it's often dangerous to expose lock objects as public (or even worse, global) fields.  In particular, it can be a recipe for deadlocks when multiple global locks are exposed and acquired in differing orders or when you have cases like blocking dispatches to the UI thread while holding a lock.  Consider looking into alternate ways to accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answer, you have to acquire the lock before you can call `Monitor.Pulse()` on the monitor object.

That said, your code has at least one other serious bug: you are not initializing the synchronization object in a thread-safe way, which could easily lead to two different threads using two different object instances, resulting in no synchronization between those threads:

```
public static object GetFirstObjectInstance
{
    get
    {
        if(o1==null)
        {
            o1=new object();
        }
        return o1;
    }
}
```

If two threads call this getter simultaneously, they each may see `o1` as `null` and try to initialize it. Then each might return a different value for the object instance.

You should simply initialize the object in a initializer:

```
private static readonly object o1 = new object();
```

And then return it from the getter:

```
public static object GetFirstObjectInstance { get { return o1; } }
```

That addresses the thread-safety issue. But you still have other issues with the code. First, you should encapsulate synchronization in an object, not expose the actual synchronization `object` instance. Second, assuming you are going to expose the synchronization object, I don't understand why you bother with the property, since you made the field public. The field should be private if you want to use a property as well.

It would also be better if the property followed normal .NET naming conventions. A method that returned the object would have "Get" in the name, but a property would not. Just name it "FirstObjectInstance".

Also as noted by Dan, use `lock` everywhere you want to acquire the lock.

There may be other issues in the code as well...I didn't do a thorough review. But the above you need to fix for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't mean to make the fields public, by the way. Just fixed them to private.